# Why doesn't this JS self-invoked function work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use an auto self-invoked functions to open and close the menu but it doesn't work.

I rely on examples I saw about self-invoked functions but now I don't know what's wrong.

I tried different syntax to call the function, but nothing worked but everything worked when I Call the funtion using "onclick=function name", so I guess that the problem is on the self-invoked function.

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="open-slide" >
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/menu.png" id="btn-open">
      </a>
    </span>
    <h1 id="t1">Innova<span id="t2">TEK</span> </h1>    
  </nav>

  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a href="#" class="btn-close">
    <img src="img/back.png" alt="" id="btn-close"></a>
    <a href="#"><img i class = "menu"src="img/home.png" alt=""> &nbsp;Home</a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="img/about.png" class = "menu"  alt=""> &nbsp; About</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/support.png" alt="">&nbsp; Services</a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="img/contact.png" alt="">&nbsp; Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Responsive Side Menu</h1>
  </div>
```

```
(function(){
    show();
    hide();
});

function show(){
    document.getElementById("btn-open").addEventListener('click', menuShow());
}

function hide(){
document.getElementById("btn-close").addEventListener("click", menuHide());
}

function menuShow(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '17%';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '17%';
}  

function menuHide(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0';
}
```

Comment: You've defined the function and enclosed it in `()` but never invoked it. `(function() { ... })()` - you're missing the pair of parens at the end.

Comment: Just so you know, this is commonly referred to as an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), which is not a self-invocation, since the function itself is not invoking it, the interpreter/compiler is just invoking it right after it has been defined due to order of operation and syntax.

Comment: There also many ways to write an IIFE (or "iffy"); `+function(){}()`, `(function{}())`, `(function{})()`, `val=function(){}()`, and the list goes on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `()` at the end of the IIFE without which the function will not call itself. Also you should have passed the function reference to the event listeners and not a function call.

Here is working code, I added some `css` for the `btn-close` so we can see it for testing.

```js
(function(){
    show();
    hide();
})();           // <--- were missing the () here

function show(){
    document.getElementById("btn-open").addEventListener('click', menuShow);
}

function hide(){
document.getElementById("btn-close").addEventListener("click", menuHide);
}

function menuShow(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '17%';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '17%';
}  

function menuHide(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0';
}
```

```css
#btn-close {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  height:20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <span class="open-slide" >
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/menu.png" id="btn-open">
      </a>
    </span>
    <h1 id="t1">Innova<span id="t2">TEK</span> </h1>    
  </nav>

  <div id="side-menu" class="side-nav">
    <a href="#" class="btn-close">
    <img src="img/back.png" alt="" id="btn-close"></a>
    <br style="clear:both" />
    <a href="#"><img i class = "menu"src="img/home.png" alt=""> &nbsp;Home</a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="img/about.png" class = "menu"  alt=""> &nbsp; About</a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/support.png" alt="">&nbsp; Services</a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="img/contact.png" alt="">&nbsp; Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Responsive Side Menu</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

friend, the functions with addEventListener should not have the parentheses to be invoked, just delete the parentheses

answer it is:

```
document.getElementById("btn-open").addEventListener('click', menuShow );
document.getElementById("btn-close").addEventListener('click', menuHide );
function menuShow(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '17%';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '17%';
} 



function menuHide(){
    document.getElementById('side-menu').style.width = '0';
    document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0';
}
```